# How to make php script pausable and resumable?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to make small script of php. And i have two buttons with name "PAUSE" and "RESUME" when i click on pause the script will be paused until i click on "RESUME".When i click on resume the script will be start at the point where it is stopped not from beginning.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What functionality do you want to achieve?

Comment: Leaving php in a hanged state is a terrible idea. You're best off using a [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement with `$_POST` and determining what to do when you send the request.

Comment: php is synchronous, you can't pause it. but there is a way you can achieve this if you have something like a data to loop on when you wan't to resume it. create an array in js or a database, then pass the values from js to php back and fort

Comment: I just want to pause php script for some time and then start again.Actually i have database with 12lac records and i want to fetch data and it take too much time so i want to pause php script for some time

Comment: Read this carefully .. https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/pause-resume-script/2577/2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/how-do-i-implement-basic-long-polling